# Case use in simple sentence

Tags: грамматика, падежи, прилагательные

Another very basic question from a beginner. In the sentence:

`Мой любимый спорт - хоккей.`

`(My favorite sport is hockey).`

I know that `мой` is the subject (and it's a possessive pronoun), so it's in the nominative case. But what about `любимый спорт`?

Is `любимый` an adjective for `спорт`?  So which case does `спорт` take?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the entire *noun phrase* **[мой любимый спорт]** is the subject of the sentence. In other words, all the elements of the phrase: the possessive adjective **мой**, the adjective **любимый** and the noun **спорт** together make up the subject.

Furthermore, the *head* of this noun phrase is the noun **спорт**. Since this is a singular masculine noun, it *governs* all the other elements in the phrase and makes them masculine and singular in form as well.

Comment: любимый originates from a particple